# Was Officer Lewis originally planned to become a RoboCop?

Tags: robocop, robocop-1987

At the end of RoboCop, there is this [interesting dialogue](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/r/robocop-script-transcript-peter-weller.html):

> **Lewis:** Murphy, I'm a mess.
>
> **RoboCop:** They'll fix you. They fix everything.

Did the writers originally intend for Lewis to come back as a RoboCop in a sequel?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Doing some digging, I came across [a version of the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Robocop.pdf) which ends with Office Lewis recovering in a hospital bed.

And after reading that I remember seeing this scene, and found it on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrhNIxYOiH0&feature=youtube_gdata_player)<sup>1</sup>; the [image below](http://www.robocoparchive.com/info/making1-cutscenes.htm) is a still from the scene.

[image: Officer Lewis recovering in hospital]

So, the answer is, **No**.

<sub>1 The video was briefly removed due to copyright violation, it is now restored.</sub>